# how can i apply fft in non multiplication problem?

Tags: algorithm

hello i'm trying to apply fft on this problem

i'm tring to optimize O(n^2) operation that found every combination of x[i] and y[j] (0 <= i,j <= N) by fft

but after spending short time on studing fft

but since it is not a multiplication operation,

i wonder whether i can apply fft on these kind of problem

would you give me any way to solve this problem?

i'm sorry for my poor english.

below is wrong answer by me,
it spent O(N^2)
, just help for understand problem

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#define MAX 262145
using namespace std;
typedef long long LL;
int N;
LL ans[MAX] = {0,};
LL c[19][2][2] = {0,}; // c [2^i][xi][yi]
int x[] = {0,0,1,1};
int y[] = {0,1,0,1};
LL A[MAX] = {0,}; //Set A
LL B[MAX] = {0,}; //Set B
LL power[18] = {0,}; //power[i] == pow(2,i)
LL cal(LL a,LL b){ // find the index number for input pair(a,b)
   LL res = 0;
   for(int i = 0 ; i < N ; i++){
       res += c[i][(a&(1<<i)) == 0 ? 0 : 1][(b&(1<<i)) == 0 ? 0 : 1] * power[i];
   }
   return res; // the result will point the index of f(x,y)
}
int main() {
   ios_base::sync_with_stdio();
   cin.tie(0);
   cout.tie(0);
   cin >> N;
   string str;
   int mv = pow(2,N);
   for(int i = 0 ; i < N ; i++){
       cin >> str;
       power[i] = pow(2,i);
       for(LL j = 0 ; j < 4 ; j++){
           c[i][x[j]][y[j]] = (int)(str[j] - '0');
       }
   }
   for(int i = 0 ; i < mv ; i++){
       cin >> A[i];
   }
   for(int i = 0 ; i < mv ; i++){
       cin >> B[i];
       if(B[i] != 0){
           for(int j = 0 ; j < mv ; j++){
               if(A[j] != 0){
                   ans[cal(j,i)] += A[j]*B[i]; //
               }        
           }
       }
   } // in this loop we use O(N^2)
   for(int i = 0 ; i < mv ; i++){
       cout << ans[i] << " ";
   }
   return 0;
}
```

problem:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mxpl0.png)

Comment: This is not a c++ question, so should not have been asked here. Try to think of the question in terms of n-bit numbers. There are no floating point numbers in this question nor is it a convolution problem... so an FFT is bound to be too complex

Comment: FYI, the expression `pow(2, i)` can be replaced with `1 << i`.  The left shift is usually one instruction on most processors.  The `pow` function requires a function call, then returns a floating point, which may have errors when converting to integer.